# How can I force a string of an integer to behave like a string when using it to deindex an associative array in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code:

```
var arr = [];

var int_str = "9";    
arr[int_str] = true;
console.log(arr);    
arr[int_str + ""] = true;
console.log(arr);    
arr[int_str.toString()] = true;
console.log(arr);
```

Giving the output:

```
[ <9 empty items>, true ]
[ <9 empty items>, true ]
[ <9 empty items>, true ]
```

In other words, when the string `int_str` is used as the key to the array `arr`, it behaves like the number 10, rather than the string "10", and 9 empty cells initialize behind the 11th.  This happens despite using `toString()`, or trying to force it in to becoming a string with `+ ""`.

The only way I can force this to behave like a string is to append an actual character like `int_str + "."`.  That's not a practical solution for me though.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "string of an integer". Strings contain strings. Arrays don't have keys, they only have numeric indexes. If you pass a string that can be converted to a non-negative whole number, then that happens and the converted number is used as an array index. There is also no such thing as an associative array in JavaScript. There are, however, objects which do that job.

Comment: I'm aware of that.  Clearly what I mean is a string whose characters only consist of '0'-'9'

Comment: Arrays don’t take arbitrary string keys.  Perhaps you want to create an object.

Comment: What do you mean arrays don't take arbitrary string keys?

Comment: Arrays only take non-numeric whole numbers as indexes. If you pass a string as an index, and the string can be converted to a non-negative number, it will be and then that number is used as the index. An arbitrary string is one that could contain a character that could be converted to a number or one that can't.

Comment: @DuncanMarshall you can set arbitrary properties on an array, but arrays treat numeric (meaning strings that look like numbers) differently than regular objects. They always become indexes. (Actually objects treat them differently too when it comes to key order).

Comment: This code: `var arr = []; arr["this string will work as a key"] = true;console.log(arr);` will output this: `[ 'this string will work as a key': true ]`  This is an array taking an arbitrary string as a key.  Semantic points aside about arrays actually being objects in Javascript, how do I get to a place where I can use a string that only consists of integers to be my array key?

Comment: @DuncanMarshall It's not semantic at all. That code doesn't do what you think it does. That code doesn't create a new array element. It creates a new property on the array object. See [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/objd016y/5/) that shows this. And, again, Arrays don't have keys. **What you want is an Object, not an Array. See my answer below.**

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Map` instead of an `array []` and simply avoid that nonsense...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Maps take strings, numbers, objects, and symbols and do not modify their key types.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to pass a string as a true "key", then you can't use an Array as Arrays only take non-numeric whole numbers as their indexes.

If you pass a string as an indexer to an array, an attempt to convert that string to a non-negative whole number is made and, if successful, that numeric index is located within the array. If not, and you are setting a value, you won't be adding a new item to the array. You'll be creating a new property on the Array instance and that value won't show up when you enumerate the array.

Examples:

```js
let myArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

console.log("Arrays:");
console.log(myArr[5]);      // 6
console.log(myArr["5"]);    // 6
console.log(myArr["ten"]);  // undefined - Arrays don't take keys

// Objects:

let myObj = {
  one:1,
  two:2,
  three:3,
  4:4,
  five:5
};

console.log("Objects:");
console.log(myObj["4"]);     // 4
console.log(myObj[4]);       // 4 - The number is treated as a string because keys are strings
console.log(myObj["five"]);  // 5
console.log(myObj[2]);       // undefined - objects don't take indexes and there is no key of 2
```